# Call a function in a injected website from Content Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

---

Is there a way to call a function in a injected website from Content Scripts?

I have a scene that need inject some code from a website, but encounter a problem that can not call a function in this website from Content Scripts.

How can i do that?

for example:

www.xxx.com has function named abc below:

```
function abc() {
   // do something
}
```

in my manifest.json defines content_scripts below:

```
  "content_scripts": [{
  "matches": ["http://www.xxx.com/*"],
  "js": ["my.js"]
  }]
```

in my.js wanted to invoke abc function below:

```
abc(); // the error occurred: ReferenceError: abc is not defined
```

The problem is how to call abc function in my.js

Comment: content scripts run in a separate isolated environment from the scripts on the page so no you cannot invoke that method. What exactly are you trying to accomplish by running that method?

Comment: the abc method is very hard to read, so use this easy way

Comment: possible duplicate of [Building a Chrome Extension - Inject code in a page using a Content script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script)